# Updating a table of 10k records efficiently in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have two tables, Table A and Table B. Table A has 10k records. Table B has those 10K old records and additional records. I need to update the old 10k records in Table B.

I used,

```
UPDATE CONTENT_WORKFLOW_MASTER CWM, CWSCOPY TMP SET
CWM.PROGRAM_ID = TMP.PROGRAM_ID,
CWM.PROGRAM_TYPE_ID = TMP.PROGRAM_TYPE_ID, 
CWM.PROGRAM_TYPE_NAME = TMP.PROGRAM_TYPE_NAME, 
CWM.ORIGINAL_TITLE = TMP.ORIGINAL_TITLE, 
CWM.SOURCE_GROUP_ID = TMP.SOURCE_GROUP_ID, 
CWM.MASTER_TITLE = TMP.MASTER_TITLE, 
CWM.PROGRAM_LANGUAGE = TMP.PROGRAM_LANGUAGE, 
CWM.REGION = TMP.REGION, 
CWM.CW_STATUS = 'NEW', 
CWM.COPY_CULTURE = TMP.COPY_CULTURE, 
CWM.GENRES = TMP.GENRES, 
CWM.AIR_DATE_TIME = TMP.AIR_DATE_TIME, 
CWM.PROCESS_ID = TMP.GUID, 
CWM.PRIORITY = 0, 
CWM.UPDATED_BY_SCHEDULE = 1, 
CWM.MODIFIED_USER = 'StoredProcUser', 
CWM.MODIFIED_DATE = NOW() WHERE CWM.PROGRAM_ID = TMP.PROGRAM_ID ;
```

And i used,

```
UPDATE CONTENT_WORKFLOW_MASTER CWM INNER JOIN t.temp TMP 
USING (PROGRAM_ID) 
SET 
CWM.PROGRAM_ID = TMP.PROGRAM_ID,
CWM.PROGRAM_TYPE_ID = TMP.PROGRAM_TYPE_ID, 
CWM.PROGRAM_TYPE_NAME = TMP.PROGRAM_TYPE_NAME, 
CWM.ORIGINAL_TITLE = TMP.ORIGINAL_TITLE, 
CWM.SOURCE_GROUP_ID = TMP.SOURCE_GROUP_ID, 
CWM.MASTER_TITLE = TMP.MASTER_TITLE, 
CWM.PROGRAM_LANGUAGE = TMP.PROGRAM_LANGUAGE, 
CWM.REGION = TMP.REGION, 
CWM.CW_STATUS = 'NEW', 
CWM.COPY_CULTURE = TMP.COPY_CULTURE, 
CWM.GENRES = TMP.GENRES, 
CWM.AIR_DATE_TIME = TMP.AIR_DATE_TIME, 
CWM.PROCESS_ID = TMP.GUID, 
CWM.PRIORITY = 0, 
CWM.UPDATED_BY_SCHEDULE = 1, 
CWM.MODIFIED_USER = 'StoredProcUser', 
CWM.MODIFIED_DATE = NOW() WHERE CWM.USER_LOCKED=0;

create TEMPORARY table t.temp AS
SELECT DISTINCT CWS.CONTENT_WORKFLOW_STAGING_ID,CWS.PROGRAM_ID,CWS.SOURCE_GROUP_NAME,CWS.COPY_CULTURE,
CWS.PROGRAM_TYPE_ID,  CWS.PROGRAM_TYPE_NAME, CWS.ORIGINAL_TITLE, CWS.SOURCE_GROUP_ID, CWS.MASTER_TITLE, 
CWS.PROGRAM_LANGUAGE, CWS.REGION, CWS.GENRES, CWS.AIR_DATE_TIME, CWS.GUID,CWS.IS_PROCESSED, CWS.INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID 
FROM CONTENT_WORKFLOW_STAGING CWS INNER JOIN CONTENT_WORKFLOW_MASTER CWM ON
CWM.PROGRAM_ID = CWS.PROGRAM_ID AND 
CWM.SOURCE_GROUP_NAME = CWS.SOURCE_GROUP_NAME AND CWM.COPY_CULTURE = CWS.COPY_CULTURE AND CWM.USER_LOCKED = 0 
AND 
CWS.IS_PROCESSED = 0 AND CWS.INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID = INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID;
```

Both the queries are not full efficient. CAn anyone suggest the efficient way to to that. Within atleast 10 sec.

Comment: Do you have indexes on these 2 tables? BTW for clarity don't use using clause use on. And don't ask about table a and table b when you query tables are different.

Comment: One table is with index and another is a temporary table in stored procedure

Comment: And Using ON also its taking pretty much time:(

Comment: Have you tried adding an index to your temporary table?

Comment: I'll post my query on creation of temporary table. Please let me know how can we add index

Comment: I figured out how to create index for my temp table,

Comment: create TEMPORARY table t.temp (INDEX temp_index(PROGRAM_ID,SOURCE_GROUP_NAME,COPY_CULTURE))

Comment: If you have a version that lets you do this, please provide `EXPLAIN UDPATE ...`

Comment: About how many rows in each table?  How many will be updated?